# Get random record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get random record with `where`. Is it possible to do it in rails? For example, I have this:

```
Post.where(available: 'true', approved:  "true").first
```

I want to get random record instead of the first one.  If it's possible to do it, will it have an effect on the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `.shuffle` on active record relation which will return you an array.

```
Post.where(available: 'true', approved:  "true").shuffle.first
```

Or

```
Post.where(available: 'true', approved:  "true").sample
```

Or more efficient way

```
Post.where(available: 'true', approved:  "true").order("RANDOM()")
```

Comment: extending @Manishh answer, you can also pass a number to `sample` method to get any number of results. e.g. `.sample(3)` will return 3 random records

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know which way would be most efficient in terms of speed and performance?

Comment: @KriloMax with order clause it will take less time as compare to other options.

Comment: Wouldn't this ```Post.where(available: 'true', approved:  "true").order("RANDOM()")``` result in pulling all the records? or should I do something like ```Post.where(available: 'true', approved:  "true").order("RANDOM()").first```

Comment: yes that up to you how many records you want. you can use take to limit number of records.